# Omitting "INTO" in "INSERT INTO" Statement

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-insert

You can apparently interchangeably include or omit `INTO` in `INSERT` statements at least both in MySQL and SQL Server:

```
-- works:
INSERT INTO Table (Column) VALUES (1);
-- also works:
INSERT Table (Column) VALUES (1);
```

Why is this and which approach should be taken?

Comment: Not really sure why this is except for ease of writing if someone for gets a command. I would always adhere to best practices and write it all out correctly.

Comment: @reformed same as `DELETE` and `DELETE FROM`